Because of New changes in Headless Testing mode in Selenium and Chrome
enter image description here
i am using selenium java version 4.19.1 with Chrome Version 123.0.6312.106 but when i am simply launching the headless testing then i am getting this error
Getting error - The method addArguments(String) is undefined for the type ChromeOptions
for reference i am adding this link please anyone go through it and provide me a solution
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/chromium/new-headless
enter image description here
